# ANT - replace xml declaration

Tags: xml, ant, replace, xml-declaration

I have an XML document composed of several other XML documents appended to it.  As a result, there are several XML declarations within the document which prevent my XSLT from parsing it correctly.  I am trying to remove the declarations from the document using the ant `replace` and `replaceregexp` tasks, but they do nothing to the file.  This is what I have so far.

```
<replaceregexp file="${cppUnit.file}" >
    <regexp pattern="&lt;?xml * ?&gt;" />
    <substitution expression="" />
</replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<replaceregexp file="${cppUnit.file}" match="&lt;\?xml.*\?&gt;"
     replace="" byline="true"/>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I'm new to ant so I didn't know how to escape those question marks.

Answer (score 0):

ok.  This worked.

```
<regexp pattern="..?xml version=.1.0. encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?..." />
```